# Button active when an option is selected

Tags: javascript

I want the button to be passive.The button should be active when an option is selected.
Only one option can be selected.

```html
<div id="form">
    <form action="#" method="post">

        <br><br>
        <input type="radio" id="terms" name="terms" onchange="on()">option 1.
        <br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="terms2" name="terms2" onchange="on()">option 2.
        <br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="terms3" name="terms3" onchange="on()">option 3.
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="gonder" disabled>Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
function on() {
   document.getElementById("gonder").removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <form action="#" method="post">

        <br><br>
        <input type="radio" id="terms" name="terms" onchange="on()">option 1.
        <br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="terms2" name="terms" onchange="on()">option 2.
        <br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="terms3" name="terms" onchange="on()">option 3.
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="gonder" disabled>Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

To select only one option, the radio inputs all need to have the same name.
To enable the Send button when an option is selected, enable it on the change event in JavaScript.

Comment: this does not make it so that user can select only one option.

Comment: Give your radio button the same names to make that happen

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer to do this now.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same `name` for all the radio `button` to select one at a time.

And also define the `onchange` method.

```js
function on() {
 $('#gender').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
    <form action="#" method="post">

        <br><br>
        <input type="radio" id="terms1" name="term" onchange="on()">option 1.
        <br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="terms2" name="term" onchange="on()">option 2.
        <br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="terms3" name="term" onchange="on()">option 3.
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="gender" disabled>Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define you go() function as in this snippet.

```
    <div id="form">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <br><br>
            <input type="radio" id="terms" name="terms" onchange="on()">option 1.
            <br><br>
            <input type="radio" id="terms2" name="terms2" onchange="on()">option 2.
            <br><br>
            <input type="radio" id="terms3" name="terms3" onchange="on()">option 3.
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" id="gonder" disabled>Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function on() {
            document.getElementById("gonder").removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

to @csgoempire

```
<div id="form">
<form action="#" method="post">
    <button id="reselect">
      reselect
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="terms" name="terms"> option 1.
    <br><br>
            <input type="radio" id="terms2" name="terms2" >option 2.
    <br><br>
            <input type="radio" id="terms3" name="terms3" >option 3.
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="gonder" disabled>Send</button>
</form>
```

hello try this one i tested already on jsfiddle

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
        if(!$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked')){
        $('input[type="radio"]').attr('disabled',true);
    };
});

$('#reselect').on('click', function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').attr('disabled',false);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a3rj4zsp/9/